# How do you install chntpw on Ubuntu 17.04?

Tags: software-installation, 17.04, archive

I downloaded the tar.gz off of the Ubuntu Package website and have tried following 3 different tutorials, and every time I try to do something terminal tells me I can't. I haven't made any progress.

Comment: Why is your title and body of the question sooo different?!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

chntpw is in the default repositories of Ubuntu 17.04 and all currently supported versions of Ubuntu. To install chntpw open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt update  
sudo apt install chntpw
```

Comment: Yeah, I did try this. For some reason it returns an error saying Unable to locate package.

Comment: Check in *Software & Updates* -> *Ubuntu Software* tab that the first four software sources in the list are checked by check marks. Don't try to install the chntpw .tar.gz file you downloaded. Use apt to install chntpw and apt will download and install chtpw for you.

Comment: Hey. It worked. I just needed you there to hold my hand. Thanks.